# jQuery image appended after div duplicates, then disappears.

Tags: jquery, css, paypal

I've got a bit of an issue where I'm trying to append an image after a div on our checkout page but what occurs is that the image appears twice as the page is loading & then disappears completely.  My instinct is that either I'm calling the image incorrectly (still fairly new to all things JS) or there's another JS function(s) causing the errors.

My code is fairly simple & is as follows, can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

```
// Add PayPal Certificate Image
// =============================================================================
function add_paypal_certificate_code(){
?>

<!-- PayPal Pro Certificate -->
<script>
jQuery(function($) { //noconflict wrapper
    $(".payment_method_paypal_pro").append("<img src='//autumnlanepaperie.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/PayPal.jpg' />");
});//end noconflict
</script>
<!-- End PayPal Pro Certificate -->

<?php 
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_paypal_certificate_code' );
// End PayPal Certificate Image
// =============================================================================
```

BTW I opted to use the image rather than the code PayPal provides due to the perceived comparative simplicity.  Their code is here, if anyone wants to see it & has a suggestion on how to do this.

```
<!-- PayPal Logo --><table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" align="center"><tr><td align="center"></td></tr><tr><td align="center"><a href="https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-popup" title="How PayPal Works" onclick="javascript:window.open('https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-popup','WIPaypal','toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=1060, height=700'); return false;"><img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/mktg/logo-center/Security_Banner_150x100_2a.gif" border="0" alt="PayPal Logo"></a></td></tr></table><!-- PayPal Logo -->
```

Comment: Hi Jeff, your code does not give a clue, when the JavaScript code is excecuted. And probably You want do delay that execution until all content is loaded (using document.onload). Try that. It could be a solution, but I can't already say that for sure regarding the code You have provided. Also a small sidenote: You should prettyfy one line html-code before posting it here. The browser might not care, the human eye does!

Comment: try moving the execution still a bit later with `$(window).load()`, if there are some other scripts that cause that duplicate and disappearance.

Comment: Apologies, Bo, you're right - I thought about it but decided nobody would want to read autogenerated code anyway, I was lazy.

diynevala, that's done it!  I was the reason for the duplicate images, turns out that class occurs twice on the page.  Leave your answer & I'll mark it as accepted - much obliged to both of you!